# Erro ao tentar acessar a sessão de admin no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Meu site esta funcionando normalmente, porem quando vou acessa a sessão de admin começa a surgir esse erro, até o dia 29 estava funcionando normalmente, fiquei esses dias sem entrar.

**O erro apresentado segue abaixo:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Http_Cookie' not found in /home/steakvillecom/public_html/prod/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-response.php:165 Stack trace: #0 /home/steakvillecom/public_html/prod/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-response.php(192): WP_HTTP_Requests_Response-

Comment: Parece que é erro de Plugin. deve ter sido algum tipo de atualização. Vc também pode perguntar na Plataforma de Wordpress do StackExchange https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Verifica se o arquivo `wp-includes/class-wp-http-cookie.php` existe, caso não exista é necessário baixa-lo e adiciona-lo.

Comment: sim existe o  wp-includes/class-wp-http-cookie.php

Comment: Então imagino que algum plugin tenha atualizado automaticamente, mas como faço para volta-lo? Se não tem como acessar a sessão.

Comment: Provavelmente no momento de fazer o upload via FTP o `wp-includes/class-wp-http-cookie.php` tenha ficado truncado, tente faze o upload novamente como BINÁRIO.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente no momento de fazer o upload via FTP o `wp-includes/class-wp-http-cookie.php` tenha ficado *truncado* (quebrou durante o upload), tente faze o upload novamente somente do `class-wp-http-cookie.php` para a pasta `/public_html/prod/wp-includes/`.

Se não funcionar tente enviar como BINÁRIO, se estiver usando o Filezilla, clique em <kbd>Transfer</kbd> > <kbd>Transfer type</kbd> > e troque <kbd>Auto</kbd> por <kbd>Binary</kbd>

Como na imagem:

[image: filezilla]